# Why does my tooltip not show as a list box

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I use the following, I see a tooltip with but instead of showing as a ListView, it shows as a single tooltip as System.Window.DataTemplate.

I thought I'd explained what DataTemplate to use... Why does the below not show the result of the DataTemplate and just the 'type'

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ToolTip}" x:Key="Tool">
        <ListView DataContext="{Binding Path=MyMix}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Mix}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyButtons">
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=MyIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Binding.SourceUpdated="ComboBox_SourceUpdated" ToolTip="{StaticResource Tool}">                    
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you do not instantiate a instance of `ToolTip`, so none gets created. (The template does not instanciate a `ToolTip` and in the ComboBox there is just an assignment to the `ToolTip` attribute which effectively calls a TypeConverter to the `DataTemplate` class.)

I tried this code...

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyMix}">
        <ToolTip>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mix}"></ListView>
        </ToolTip>
    </DataTemplate>           
</Grid.Resources>
```

but this gave me this error: *'ToolTip' cannot have a logical or visual parent*

Another thing I'm not sure about: Aren't `DataTemplates` more used for "source objects", that means data? In your code, the Type used for the `DataTemplate` is the visual class, the `ToolTip`.

**Solution?**

So I ended up setting the tooltip on the `ComboBox` directly.
Is this ok for you?
I am not sure whether I understood your data model correctly.
It works, but because it is not a template, this tooltip is not re-usable anywhere else.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
            <ComboBox.ToolTip>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyMix.Mix}" ></ListView>
            </ComboBox.ToolTip>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```